# How to get all derived classes from a base class in C++?

Tags: c++, class, templates, types, entity-component-system

I'm implementing a game engine in C++ which uses an ECS (Entity-Component-System).

Each `GameObject` can have multiple `Component`s (stored in `GameObject`'s `std::vector<Component*> _components`).

I have a method that allows me to get a `Component` of a `GameObject` by specifying the type of `Component` I want:

```cpp
// In GameObject.h
template <typename T> T* GetComponent() {
    for (Component* c : _components) {
        if (typeid(*c) == typeid(T)) return (T*)c;
    }
    return nullptr;
}
```

```cpp
// In main.cpp
RandomComponent* RC = gameObject.GetComponent<RandomComponent>();
```

Now let's say I have those `Component`s defined:

```cpp
class TerrainComponent { /* ... */ }
class PerlinTerrainComponent : public TerrainComponent { /* ... */ }
class FlatTerrainComponent : public TerrainComponent { /* ... */ }
// And possibly many more
```

And have world `GameObject`s, which all have a `TerrainComponent`'s derived class attached to it.

My problem is that I would need a way to get the `TerrainComponent` of a world, like so:

```cpp
TerrainComponent* TC = world.GetComponent<TerrainComponent>();
```

And get any type of `TerrainComponent` attached to the world (which, in reality, will be a `TerrainComponent` derived class).

Is it possible, in C++, to implement a method that would allow me to do that (get all derived classes of a class), without having to manually update a list of `TerrainComponent` derived classes?

Comment: Not sure to understand your question but maybe if you replace if (typeid(*c) == typeid(T)) by if(dynamic_cast<T*>(c) != nullptr ) it will do what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming these classes are all polymorphic/dynamic (which they need to be to use typeid like this), you can just use dynamic_cast instead:

```
template <typename T> T* GetComponent() {
    for (Component* c : _components) {
        if (T *tc = dynamic_cast<T *>(c)) return tc;
    }
    return nullptr;
}
```

Comment: Notice this only works if the objects are polymorphic, ie with at least one virtual method.

Comment: @Jellyboy: as does the `typeid` method.

Comment: Had not thought about a `dynamic_cast`. It did what I was looking for! Thanks